# target: "current" is not working from JS do_action()

Tags: javascript, python, odoo, odoo-8

I'm  trying to open tree view from JS. I'm able to open a pop up with target: "new", but when given as target: "current" its just showing loading symbol on the top but its not opening the view in current page. Any help would be appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
var action = {
            name: "student details",
            context: this.session.user_context,
            res_model: 'student.details',
            views: [[false, 'list']],
            type: 'ir.actions.act_window',
            target: "current",
            auto_search : true,
            flags: {
                sidebar: false,
                deletable: false,
                views_switcher: false,
                action_buttons: false,
                search_view: false,
                pager: false,
                radio: true,
                }
            };
            var am = new openerp.web.ActionManager(this);
            am.do_action(action);
```